# Use 'last-child' and 'starts with' together like div[attr^=value_]:last-child

Tags: html, css

I have to select classes starts with `num_` and want to apply different property on there `last-child` have no other option to add extra classes or attributes.

I tried with `#divMenu div[class^='num_']:last-child` but not able to reach there.

Please have a look at [HTML](https://jsfiddle.net/ashish41191/uo1tamfL/)

Have any idea ??

Comment: Could you post your html?

Comment: Your selector should work - http://jsfiddle.net/a278z5yq/1/

Comment: it works fine http://jsfiddle.net/1uahu8g5/ you might be using some wrong selectors post your HTML so that we can suggest you CSS

Comment: sorry i am not able to post it here... coz it adds different element dynamically  and i have no rights to acces its html code to make changes @Danield

Comment: I have a feeling the problem is a misunderstanding of `:last-child` ... something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/yLrwvnjf/) won't work because there is no `:last-of-class` selector

Comment: @Danield please wait for a while i am trying to get html

Comment: @Danield please check i updated my question with link

Comment: @AshishMishra Just a **small** and **formatted** sample of code would be **much** better.

Comment: @Paulie_D you are right .. but i am confused in that ...so i post exactly the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because none of the `div[class^='num_']` are actually `last-child`'s.

In your example, in order for the #categoryPanel_2 element to be a `last-child` you'll have to get rid of it's adjacent sibling:

```
<div class="x-clear" role="presentation" id="ext-gen1332"></div>
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/danield770/uo1tamfL/2/) (with adjacent sibling commented out)

Comment: Sir... its just for an example.. the num_ is actully #categoryPanel_

Comment: is there a way to select that particular class with out any modification on html

Comment: Or is we able to apply  '#divMenu div[id^='categoryPanel_']:last-child:not(.x-clear)' ?

Comment: No, since your html is dynamic and you don't know the id/class names nor the html structure - i don't think it is possible with just css

Answer (score 1):

This will help you for all the classes starting with test we need to create a parent class and set the style for the last-child check the below code

```css
div.test div[class^="test"]:last-child {
    background: #ffff00;
}
```

```html
<div class="first_test">The first div element.</div>
<div class="second">The second div element.</div>
<div class="test">
   <div class="test_50">The third div element.</div>
   <div class="test_50">The third div element.</div>
   <div class="test_50">The third div element.</div>
</div>
<p class="test">This is some text in a paragraph.</p>
```

Kindly check this code. It works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/hw5dmbg0/1/)

You can select like this.

```
    p[class^="sel_"]:last-child{color: red}
```